# mysql replication fail (no error)

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-replication, database-replication, mysql5.6

I'm doing a replication on a mysql 5.6 server (master) to a slave in mixed mode.
The thing is, i connect to mysql trought workbench, i execute querys and are replicated.
But if another user connected through the same way, deletes a register, it is deleted on the master, but not replicated on the slave. So the register stills appear.
I don't understand why it doesn't shows an error. It continuous replicating till some tries to insert a register with the same ID (as it is not deleted) and then it fails showing a duplicate entry.

Does anyone knows how to se a log where it shows the errors? Why it continuous replicating and not executing that query?

Thank you

Comment: I can only think of a record not getting replicated if you use `set sql_log_bin=0` before you run a query, that won't get logged in the binary hence not replicated to the slave.

Comment: this is not what happens. we are not setting sql_log_bin=0. Also, all querys are replicated, not the one that deletes rows.

Comment: are there any replication filters on the slave?

Comment: only replicate-do-db, sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES, symbolic-links=0

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know why that happened, however i change the replica to row based and it is working.

Thanks